# running Python script within Spyder does not show output in Console

Tags: python

I've created a script in Spyder.  If I step through each line I see the output in the console.  HOwever, if I click on the green "play" button to run the script, I see this message in the console,

[pic of console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6fgy.png)

However, if I F9 the last instruction, I get the expected output,
[pic of console after F9 last script instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3b2e.png)

Here is the code:

```
path="C:/Users/jeriv/Documents/Python/ML_Andew_NG/data"
os.chdir(path)
file="ex1data1.txt"
data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=['Population', 'Profit'])
data.head()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should see if `runfile()` have an option such as `stdout` and `buffer`. Usually this behavior arise when you run a script inside a script. The launcher will buffer the script output and dump the whole thing in one go instead of line by line. I think this has less to do with Spyder and more with the console being used iPython(because of the screenshots)

Comment: I modified data.heat() to print(data.head()) and that displays the output in the console.  Not sure I understand why F9'ing  data.head() displays the output in the console, but executing that same instruction within the script when it is run does not.  Thanks for your help @dmb.